# How do I echo a TAB char on a command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

On a windows batch file, what is the proper way to echo a <kbd>TAB</kbd>?

```
echo A<TAB>B<TAB>C
```

I know I can type the <kbd>TAB</kbd> char between entries, but most editors will display it as a sequence of spaces. Some will even automatically convert them to spaces, I'm looking for something more visual.

**Clarification:** `<TAB>` here means the real tab char. I'm looking for the the C \t in a batch script.

Comment: You tried editors and found "most" display tab as a sequence of spaces? which are those?  The first editor i'd have tried is notepad and that displays tabs as tabs.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just hit the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key in an editor that supports it, Notepad for example.

So, if I enter this:

```
@echo 1<TAB>b
@echo 2<TAB>c
```

It would result in this:

[image]

Comment: It works, and it's how I'm doing it. The problem is that anyone editing the file might replace an oddly positioned tab withouth noticing it's intentional.

Comment: @Haas: What about `set TAB=<TAB>` to clarify that it is the tab character and then using `%TAB%` afterwards? As far as I am aware, `echo` only parses `%...%`. There is no built-in tab character as far as I'm aware of...

Comment: @barlop: What...............? xD

Comment: I use the suggestion of Tom Wijsman, but with quoting. `SET "TAB=   "` where the whitespace is actually a TAB (0x09) character. It is clearly suboptimal, but it seems to be the best alternative I have seen.

Comment: To get the TAB character when pressing the TAB key, you must start command prompt like `cmd /F:OFF` to disable auto-completion of file/dir. names...

Answer (score 12):

One solution is that you can set an environment variable called TAB and set the value to the actual tab character. You may need to copy and paste the tab character from a text editor to get it to be entered correctly. I have tried this in Windows 7 and it works.

In your batch file, just use %TAB% and it will insert a tab character.

Comment: +1 sombody voted you down maybe if this answer can be found somewhere in the comments. But answers should be found in the answers and not in the comments therefore an upvote from me

Comment: Yip this one is the best as it saves dealing with unknown tabs as there wouldn't be easily spotted otherwise. `set tab1="<TAB>" & set tab2="<TAB><TAB>"` etc....

Answer (score 2):

Limitations such as this are among the reasons to use Windows Script Host or Powershell.

Windows Script Host [shipped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CScript#Version_history) (ships) with every Windows version from 98 on and can be installed on 95 and NT 4.

Create a file called `demo.vbs` and paste the following line in it and save it.

```
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "a" + chr(9) + "b"
```

Now, from the directory where you saved it, enter:

```
demo.vbs
```

and you should see:

```
a       b
```

You can also do

```
cscript demo.vbs
```

which will allow you to use the command line switches that `cscript` provides.

(Tested on Vista.)

Comment: Powershell would be very nice, but it's not always availible...

Comment: @Haas: Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. I'd love to use something newer and better, but it's the one option I have for this specific script.

Comment: @Haas: I just thought that "I'm looking for something more visual" was a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one line solution using powershell in a batch file:

```
Powershell -noprofile -nologo -command Write-Output "a`tb`tc"
```

the `t is the tab character

Comment: Ah, powershell is taboo unless someone has already said it.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are using an editor that keeps the tabs intact, you could download [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) and put it on your path, and then you could do something like:

```
echo "A`B`C" | sed 's/\t/<TAB>/g'
```

where each ` is standing in for a real tab.

---

Answer (score 1):

echo a TAB char on a command prompt:

```
set "string=echo A<TAB>B<TAB>C"

set "string=%string:<TAB>=0x09%"
type nul > tmp
forfiles /m "tmp" /c "cmd /c %string%"
```

Tested on Win 10 cmd

Answer (score -1):

Basic way, but not well known, is to send <kbd>TAB</kbd> to CMD by using plain ASCII chr(9). This special char can be invoke by pressing 9 on numerical keyboard while holding Left-ALT in the same time. Char which look as bolded O should appear, otherwise some sort of encoding or keyboard mapping is on.

If your Editor was set to plain ASCII encoding, or binary mode, you can save this sequence to file. If you dont have such one, try typying CMD:

`ECHO a (sequence LALT+9) b > tabchk.bat
    tabchk.bat`

Comment: How is it better / different than just pressing tab itself?